# Persistence Lifetime not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, persistent

[image]I have configured Persistence Lifetime on Magento 2 but it's not working as expected. I have configured 60 seconds cookie lifetime but it's not affecting the same. I have checked with default Magento 2 version 2.1.5 but no luck.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

yes so one thing we have to consider always whenever we developing magento 2 project is
either disable all cache or clear,flush cache after change in admin panel of magento.
**hope it helps.**